# Django : confused datetimefiled with timezone?

Tags: python, django

**EDIT:**

I take @flyingfoxlee 's  advice

I save directely in `UTC` with :

```
#models.py
datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True,auto_now=True) 
#settings.py
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_TZ = False  #I found USE_TZ = true still save the time with +8 ??? Which should I use??
```

but in my postgreSQL database the time is `2014-10-23 09:27:38.157022+08`

And I use terminal to print out , The time is:

```
>>> obj.datetime
datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 23, 1, 27, 38, 157022)
```

So did I save `UTC` correctly ???
Please guide me Thank you

**original question:**

I want to save the variale `today` with timezome 'Asia/Taipei'

here is my code:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time(), pytz.utc)
tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Taipei')
today = tz.normalize(dt.astimezone(tz)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

abd my django model :

```
 datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True,auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

But when it saved ,the database shows `2014-10-22 08:00:00+08`

if I change to `today = tz.normalize(dt.astimezone(tz)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

the database shows `2014-10-23 05:19:01+08`

But the real time should be:`2014-10-22 21:25:23`

Why can't it save the right time??
Please guide me how to save DateTimeField
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What is `dt` exactly, I think you should save datetime in the datebase in `utc`, and change it to whichever timezone in the `frontend`.
You don't need to convert dt to `str` to save the datetime, a datetime object can be saved to the database directly.

There is a `+8` at the end of the `datetime` object is because you are saving the datetime in `Asia/Taipei timezone`, if you save it in `utc`, the `+8` will disappear and will be what you want.

Comment: how can I save in````utc```` ?  I use ````datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True,auto_now=True) ```` and  ````USE_TZ = False````  but the time is ````2014-10-23 09:27:38.157022+08````  still have ````+8````

Comment: @user2492364 Where did you save the dt to db, and where do you get the dt from db, is the value returned the same as the one saved. Where did you get your datetime from the db, if you are looking directly at postgresql,  maybe it's because your postgresql setting.